# How to find correct vector/array similarity in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, similarity, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to find a suitable way to compare 2 arrays/vectors, not based on direct boolean comparisons but on a scale or gradient [0,1]. The closest thing that works is cosine similarity, but even that doesn't seem to be what im looking for.

Example:

```
from scipy import spatial

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,10])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

print(1 - spatial.distance.cosine(a,b))
```

Which gives `0.9460998335825321` and works for me.

But for cases like:

```
from scipy import spatial

a = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

print(1 - spatial.distance.cosine(a,b))
```

It should not give `0.9045340337332909` ... I'm expecting a much lower number like 0.2. What is a good tool to use here?

Thanks

Comment: Found the correct one: its called the 'braycurtis' distance: `spatial.distance.braycurtis`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the angle between them to se how far is one from the other, if the angle is closer to 0 then one is a mulple of the other (they're almost the same, have the same direction), if the angle is closer to 180 degrees they are opposite vectors.

yo can do this to compute the angle:

```
import numpy as np
import math

v1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
v2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,10])

def magnitude(v):
    return np.sqrt(v.dot(v))

def angle(v1,v2):
    #returns the angle between two vectors
    a = np.arccos(v1.dot(v2)/(magnitude(v1)*magnitude(v2)))
    return math.degrees(a) #standarize the angle from 0 to 1 with a = 1-(a/180)
```

Comment: But is that not just the same exact thing the cosine similarity does?